# How to custom paint a gradient with the use of color filter modes? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, gradient, linear-gradients

I can't seem to find a way to add blend modes into gradients. I'm wanting to play around with transparency and blend modes to achieve some great looking styling and I feel like this is something you could do with custom paint but I'm not sure where to look.

This is that I have (with the use of a package for geadient borders):

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: const GradientBoxBorder(
                        width: 2,
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color(0x26ffffff),
                            Color(0x42ffffff),
                            Color(0x47ffffff),
                            Color(0x66ffffff)
                          ],
                          stops: [0, 0.35, 0.45, 1],
                          begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          end: Alignment.topLeft,
                        ),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                    ),
```

I'm just looking for a solution to slot in on the colors property or alterativly a custom painted gradient. Thanks for your help.